# How can I automate testing of updated dependencies with Python?

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

Usually a python library depends on multiple other dependencies and it does specify these dependences using a range like `foobar>=2.0.1`

I am looking for a way to check if newer versions of the dependencies do introduce incompatibilities or not, and eventually to safe this information.

If they break something is very easy to ban those versions by adding something like `!=2.0.2`.

More difficile is to mark validations, like annotating the fact that it passed testing with a version.

Please note that I am looking for a way to automate this process. Also, note that upgrading dependencies to the latest version that passed the tests is not an acceptable option because it could introduce dependency deadlocks.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are going to be doing this type of testing, but in my work-life, our CI pipeline is responsible for this and we have a pipeline responsible for dependency updates.

Comment: Ultimately, the way this will work, is if a new version is released, a branch is created with those dependencies in the CI, and tests are run against it. We get our feedback and decide if we want to merge or not. These updates get propagated to all projects that will use this dependency, so it is all done at "once".

Comment: @idjaw what is the outcome of the tests? Where do you save the results? Do you update requirements.txt file? Finding newer version and triggering builds is not an issue, the issue so far is that I don't know how to store and maintain that information.

Comment: We have a couple of different solutions for this. The one most excensively used (and are looking to replace, actually) is maven. Ultimately, what will happen is a "proposalbot" will be responsible for "checking" for new tags/versions of that dependency. The series of tests that are run are actually the normal unit/integration tests for the application that might inherit this dependency in order to validate that full functionality exists.

Comment: This proposalbot runs on a scheduled basis because of how heavy it can get. Sometimes, we run a manual job if we absolutely need something ASAP

Comment: These versions are then updated in the pom.xml file (maven's dependency and steps list).

Comment: Another solution we have is we make use of an upper_constraints file that compiles all of our constraints using [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools). Using this we have full control over what versions are being used and working in several of the pieces in our stack. We can run our tests with this upper_constraints file, and ensure that we have uniform functionality because of the same versions across our applications. So when things pass in our CI, we can confidently update the file, which is propagated to other projects (and tests run there too).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use `tox` https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

tox can create multiple virtual envs to test with different dependencies

suppose you want to test the dependency `foobar` from version 1.0.0 till 2.0.0

You can define a 10 different test envs by using tox and just run tox to trigger 10 different tests run in 10 isolated env with `foobar 1.0`, `foobar 1.1` till `foobar 2.0`

Please have a look at `matrix of dependencies` in `tox`

If it takes too much time to run 10 times tests suite in 10 isolated env, you maybe try to use `detox`, which can make efficient use of multiple CPUs by running all possible activities in parallel
`detox` see https://github.com/tox-dev/detox